# Find nearest test results before and after an medical appointment

Tags: python, pandas

I like to understand in general how to approach this problem at work. I have a list of dates for patient appointments. I also have another list of datas for patient test results (not necessarily on the same day of the appointments). How do I find the nearest testt results before and after an appointment date for the same patient.

I have tried to put all dates for both appointments and test results into a pandas dataframe and use a variable (event) to indicate the types of dates (test or appointment). There is a value column recording the values of the tests and null for appointment dates. Then I got stuck without knowing how to proceed. I am thinking to use groupby(patient) to get the records for each patient and go from there, but could not figure out the next step.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could make use of [Merge asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) i.e. `result_df = pd.merge_asof(patient_appts, test_results, by = 'patient_name', on = 'date', direction = 'nearest')` to generate a dataframe with the nearest test date for each patients appointment.